# Failed to load com.saprk.demo.Hive. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.saprk.demo.Hive

Tags: apache-spark

package com.saprk.demo

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Hive {

def main(args: Array[String]) {

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://user/hive/warehouse")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("create database employee")
spark.sql("show databases").show()
```

}

}

I am trying to create a database in Hive through spark and while submitting this on amazon emr  i am getting exception

> Failed to load com.saprk.demo.Hive. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.saprk.demo.Hive

Comment: 1) How are you submitting the application? 2) Is it `com.saprk.demo.Hive` or `com.spark.demo.Hive`? 3) Why don't you have `packagae com.spark.demo.Hive` at the top of your Scala code?

Comment: i am trying to run this code on amazon emr but it shows the classnotfound exception.